# What is the efficient way to search post with pictures/images?

Tags: support, search, images

I have answered quite a few posts with pictures/images. Is there a way to search MSE so that it lists all my posts, where I have used an image/picture?

Comment: It is annoying that the SE search does not find "i.stack.imgur.com" when it appears in the markup for an answer. A Google search will return any question that you've answered with an image in the question or any answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/112593/your-posts-with-images) should retrieve all your posts with images. It finds 72 such posts for you; let me know if any are missing. (Some very recent posts may be missing, because data.SE is not real-time.)

Answer (score 8):

You could search for answers with urls containing imgur using the syntax [url:"*\imgur*"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*imgur*%22). (Or you can also try [png](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*png*%22+is:a),
[jpg](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*jpg*%22+is:a),
[gif](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*gif*%22+is:a), ... )
This is not perfect, but since images uploded through the editor automatically go to imgur, this search should at least return most of such posts.

Some related posts on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [How can I sort answers that comprise at least 1 picture by votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353142)
- Feature request: [Add “hasImage:1” or “img:1” advanced search operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156639) (and other [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/156639))

---

Here is my original answer which I posted when this question was asked - but the suggestion I have added above is probably a better way to search for images.

I would also try good old  Google: for example searching for something like [imgur user17762 site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=imgur+user17762+site:math.stackexchange.com). Of course, this does not return only your posts - it includes the post where you have commented, other answer had picture etc. But if you are trying to find a specific post and you can think of other possible keywords to refine your query, this way might be useful.

Maybe even trying to use [the same query](http://images.google.com/images?q=imgur+user17762+site:math.stackexchange.com) in Google Images might be a reasonable idea. You will see the images there, so this might be handy when looking for a particular post (or for a particular picture).

Note that searching for [user:17762 imgur](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17762+imgur) using SE search engine does not return anything.